# Removing every second element out of that array in python

Tags: python

I am using codewars.com to exercise my learning in python 3. I am new to this language. This is the exercise that I have to do.

> Take an array and remove every second element out of that array.
>   Always keep the first element and start removing with the next
>   element.

And this is an example, to make it clearer:

```
my_list = ['Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep', ...]
```

I understand that the elements of an array start counting from zero, I also understand that starting from one, odd numbers start counting. If I delete the items with odd keys, I would be doing the exercise.
I have no idea where to start, but this was my attempt:

```
def remove_every_other(my_list):

    for i in my_list:
        if my_list[i] % 2 != 0:
            my_list[i]
    return my_list
```

any other idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do slicing:

```
new_list = my_list[::2]
```